# how could I close DRM mod debug print

Tags: ubuntu, drm

DRM mod print log that more then 10 lines per second.I work on ubuntu12.04.And DRM modinfo as:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.5.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/drm.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    DRM shared core routines
author:         Gareth Hughes, Leif Delgass, José Fonseca, Jon Smirl
srcversion:     769B61070F6EB3D96F43DBD
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.5.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           edid_fixup:Minimum number of valid EDID header bytes (0-8, default 6) (int)
parm:           debug:Enable debug output (int)
parm:           vblankoffdelay:Delay until vblank irq auto-disable [msecs] (int)
parm:           timestamp_precision_usec:Max. error on timestamps [usecs] (int)
```

My Question is how could I insmod this mod with deug:disable on boot?

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/default/grub`,
change line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="drm.debug=0xe plymouth:debug"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`

This workaround corrects a shutdown bug as well (sometimes fails to power off).